# File ownership after docker cp

Tags: docker, file-permissions

How can I control which user owns the files I copy in and out of a container?

The [`docker cp` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description) says this about file ownership:

> The `cp` command behaves like the Unix `cp -a` command in that directories are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible. Ownership is set to the user and primary group at the destination. For example, files copied to a container are created with `UID:GID` of the root user. Files copied to the local machine are created with the `UID:GID` of the user which invoked the `docker cp` command. However, if you specify the `-a` option, `docker cp` sets the ownership to the user and primary group at the source.

It says that files copied to a container are created as the root user, but that's not what I see. I create two files owned by user id 1005 and 1006. Those owners are translated into the container's user namespace. The `-a` option seems to make no difference when I copy the file into a container.

```
$ sudo chown 1005:1005 test.txt
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1005 1005 29 Oct  6 12:43 test.txt
$ docker volume create sandbox1
sandbox1
$ docker run --name run1 -vsandbox1:/data alpine echo OK
OK
$ docker cp test.txt run1:/data/test1005.txt
$ docker cp -a test.txt run1:/data/test1005a.txt
$ sudo chown 1006:1006 test.txt
$ docker cp test.txt run1:/data/test1006.txt
$ docker cp -a test.txt run1:/data/test1006a.txt
$ docker run --rm -vsandbox1:/data alpine ls -l /data
total 16
-rw-r--r--    1 1005     1005            29 Oct  6 19:43 test1005.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 1005     1005            29 Oct  6 19:43 test1005a.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 1006     1006            29 Oct  6 19:43 test1006.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 1006     1006            29 Oct  6 19:43 test1006a.txt
```

When I copy files out of the container, they are always owned by me. Again, the `-a` option seems to do nothing.

```
$ docker run --rm -vsandbox1:/data alpine cp /data/test1006.txt /data/test1007.txt
$ docker run --rm -vsandbox1:/data alpine chown 1007:1007 /data/test1007.txt
$ docker cp run1:/data/test1006.txt .
$ docker cp run1:/data/test1007.txt .
$ docker cp -a run1:/data/test1006.txt test1006a.txt
$ docker cp -a run1:/data/test1007.txt test1007a.txt
$ ls -l test*.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 don  don  29 Oct  6 12:43 test1006a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 don  don  29 Oct  6 12:43 test1006.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 don  don  29 Oct  6 12:47 test1007a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 don  don  29 Oct  6 12:47 test1007.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1006 1006 29 Oct  6 12:43 test.txt
$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get complete control of file ownership, I used the [tar stream](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) feature of `docker cp`:

> If `-` is specified for either the `SRC_PATH` or `DEST_PATH`, you can also stream a tar archive from `STDIN` or to `STDOUT`.

I launch the `docker cp` process, then stream a tar file to or from the process. As the tar entries go past, I can adjust the ownership and permissions however I like.

Here's a simple example in Python that copies all the files from `/outputs` in the `sandbox1` container to the current directory, excludes the current directory so its permissions don't get changed, and forces all the files to have read/write permissions for the user.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError
import tarfile

def main():
    export_args = ['sudo', 'docker', 'cp', 'sandbox1:/outputs/.', '-']
    exporter = Popen(export_args, stdout=PIPE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(fileobj=exporter.stdout, mode='r|')
    tar_file.extractall('.', members=exclude_root(tar_file))
    exporter.wait()
    if exporter.returncode:
        raise CalledProcessError(exporter.returncode, export_args)

def exclude_root(tarinfos):
    print('\nOutputs:')
    for tarinfo in tarinfos:
        if tarinfo.name != '.':
            assert tarinfo.name.startswith('./'), tarinfo.name
            print(tarinfo.name[2:])
            tarinfo.mode |= 0o600
            yield tarinfo

main()
```

Answer (score 35):

You can also change the ownership by logging in as root user into the container :

```
docker exec -it --user root <container-id> /bin/bash
chown -R <username>:<groupname> <folder/file>
```

Comment: Nice!
You may as well optimize it with: 
`docker exec -it --user root <container-id> chown -R <username>:<groupname> <folder/file>`

Answer (score 21):

In addition to @Don Kirkby's answer, let me provide a similar example in bash/shell script for the case that you want to copy something into a container while applying different ownership and permissions than those of the original file.

Let's create a new container from a small image that will keep running by itself:

```
docker run -d --name nginx nginx:alpine
```

Now wel'll create a new file which is owned by the current user and has default permissions:

```
touch foo.bar
ls -ahl foo.bar
>> -rw-rw-r-- 1 my-user my-group 0 Sep 21 16:45 foo.bar
```

Copying this file into the container will set ownership and group to the `UID` of my user and preserve the permissions:

```
docker cp foo.bar nginx:/foo.bar
docker exec nginx sh -c 'ls -ahl /foo.bar'
>> -rw-rw-r--    1 4098     4098           0 Sep 21 14:45 /foo.bar
```

Using a little `tar` work-around, however, I can change the ownership and permissions that are applied inside of the container.

```
tar -cf - foo.bar --mode u=+r,g=-rwx,o=-rwx --owner root --group root | docker cp - nginx:/
docker exec nginx sh -c 'ls -ahl /foo.bar'
>> -r--------    1 root     root           0 Sep 21 14:45 /foo.bar
```

`tar` options explained:

- `c` creates a new archive instead of unpacking one.
- `f -` will write to `stdout` instead of a file.
- `foo.bar` is the input file to be packed.
- `--mode` specifies the permissions for the target. Similar to `chown`, they can be given in symbolic notation or as an octal number.
- `--owner` sets the new owner of the file.
- `--group` sets the new group of the file.

`docker cp -` reads the file that is to be copied into the container from `stdin`.

This approach is useful when a file needs to be copied into a created container before it starts, such that `docker exec` is not an option (which can only operate on running containers).

Comment: I had trouble using a non-root user within the docker-container. I've solved this by listing the file in the container with '-n', thus 'docker exec nginx sh -c 'ls -ahln /foo.bar' and using the number on the tar parameter, thus 'tar -cf - foo.bar --mode u=+r,g=-rwx,o=-rwx --owner 1000 --group 1000 | docker cp - nginx:/'

Answer (score 9):

Just a one-liner (similar to @ramu's answer), using **root** to make the call:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it <container-id> chown node:node /home/node/myfile
```