# Docker persisted volum has no permissions (Apache Solr)

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, file-permissions, docker-volume

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
solr:
    image: solr:8.6.2
    container_name: myproject-solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./data/solr:/var/solr/data
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.42
```

After bringing up the docker with `docker-compose up -d --build`, the solr container is down and the log (`docker logs myproject-solr`) shows this:

```
Copying solr.xml
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/solr/data/solr.xml': Permission denied
```

I've noticed that if I give full permissions on my machine to the data directory `sudo chmod 777 ./data/solr/ -R` and I run the Docker again, everything is fine.

I guess the issue comes when the `solr` user is not my machine, because Docker creates the `data/solr` folder with `root:root`. Having my `./data` folder gitignored, I cannot manage these folder permissions.

I'd like to know a workaround to manage permissions properly with the purpose of persisting data

Answer (score 15):

It's a known "issue" with docker-compose: all files created by Docker engine are owned by root:root. Usually it's solved in one of the two ways:

1. Create the volume in advance. In your case, you can create the ./data/solr directory in advance, with appropriate permissions. You might make it accessible to anyone, or, better, change its owner to the `solr` user. The `solr` user and group ids are hardcoded inside the solr image: 8983 ([Dockerfile.template](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/9c3a13c0683edc2e68ac69c1f2e31f53b65fc000/Dockerfile.template#L27))

```sh
mkdir -p ./data/solr
sudo chown 8983:8983 ./data/solr
```

2. If you want to avoid running additional commands before docker-compose, you can create additional container which will fix the permissions:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  initializer:
    image: alpine
    container_name: solr-initializer
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: |
      /bin/sh -c "chown 8983:8983 /solr"
    volumes:
      - ./data/solr:/solr
    
  solr:
    depends_on: 
      - initializer
    image: solr:8.6.2
    container_name: myproject-solr
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./data/solr:/var/solr/data  
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.42
```

Comment: It would be possible to add the 'initializer' entrypoint to the solr container in any way (entrypoint in the container or writing it in a Dockerfile that uses solr image)?

Answer (score 8):

There is **docker-compose-only** solution :)

## Problem

Docker mounts local folders with root permissions.

In Solr's docker image, the default user is `solr` - for a good reason: Solr commands should be run with this user (you can force to run them with `root` but [that is not recommended](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/taking-solr-to-production.html#create-the-solr-user)).

Most Solr commands require write permissions to `/var/solr/`, for data and logs storage.

In this context, when you run a solr command as the `solr` user, you are rejected because you don't have write permission to `/var/solr/`.

## Solution

What you can do is to first start the container as root to change the permissions of `/var/solr/`. And then switch to `solr` user to run all necessary solr commands. You can't start our Solr server.

In the example below, we use [solr-precreate](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/master/scripts/solr-precreate) to create a default core and start solr.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  solr:
    image: solr:8.5.2
    volumes:
      - ./mnt/solr:/var/solr
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    user: root # run as root to change the permissions of the solr folder
    # Change permissions of the solr folder, create a default core and start solr as solr user
    command: bash -c "
      chown -R 8983:8983 /var/solr
      && runuser -u solr -- solr-precreate default-core"
```

Comment: Why is this not in the official instructions?  And why do they distribute a broken container?

Comment: If you don't mount anything, there is no permission issue. As for the official instructions... well I am not a maintainer :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Set with a Dockerfile

It's possibly not exactly what you wanted as the files aren't persisted when rebuilding the container, but it solves the 'rights' problem. Copy the files over and chown them with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM solr:8.7.0
COPY --chown=solr ./data /var/solr/data
```

This is more useful if you're trying to initialise a single core:

```
FROM solr:8.7.0
COPY --chown=solr ./core /var/solr/data/someCollection
```

It also has the advantage that you can create an image for reuse.

#### With a named volume

For persistence, you can also create a volume (in this case `core`) and copy the contents of a directory (also called `core` here), assigning the rights to the files on the way:

```sh
docker container create --name temp -v core:/data tianon/true || exit $?
tar -cf - --directory core --owner 8983 --group 8983 . | docker cp - temp:/data
docker rm temp
```

> This was adapted from these answers:
>
> - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25245#issuecomment-365980572
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52446394

Then you can mount the named volume in your Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  solr:
    image: solr:8.7.0
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - 8983:8983
    volumes:
      - core:/var/solr/data/someCollection

volumes:
  core:
    external: true
```

This solution persists the data without overriding the data on the host. And it doesn't need the extra build step. And can obviously be adapted for mounting the entire `/var/solr/data` folder.

It doesn't seem to matter that the mounted volume/directory doesn't have the correct rights (`/var/solr/data/someCollection` has owner root:root).