# Docker-compose and named volume permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is docker-compose that uses base Dockerfile created image for application.

Dockerfile looks similar to below. Some lines are omitted for reason.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN set -e -x ;\
    apt-get -y update ;\
    apt-get -y upgrade ;

...

USER service
```

When using this image in docker-compose and adding named volume to service, folder in named volume is not accessible, with message `Permission denied`. Part from docker-compose looks as below.

```yml
version: "3.1"
    services:
        myapp:
            image: myappimage
            command:
                - /myapp
            ports:
                - 12345:1234
            volumes:
                - logs-folder:/var/log/myapp

volumes:
    logs-folder:
```

My assumption was that `USER service` line is issue, which I confirmed by setting `user: root` in myapp service.

Now, question is next. I would like to avoid manually creating volume and setting permissions. I would like it to be automated using docker-compose.

Is this possible and if yes, how can this be done?

Comment: are you able to do the same in docker compose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a trick. Not really in the docker-compose file, but in the Docker file. You need to create the `/var/log/myapp` folder and set its permissions before switching to the `service` user:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN useradd myservice
RUN mkdir /var/log/myapp
RUN chown myservice:myservice /var/log/myapp

...

USER myservice:myservice
```

Docker-compose will preserve permissions.

See [Docker Compose mounts named volumes as 'root' exclusively](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3270)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I wanted to avoid this, since image is created using bazel build tool, and I am not sure where will it be created. 
I think same issue happens with host folders mounted as volumes, am i right?

Comment: @EnterSB With host folders it's even worst, the trick above won't work. There is another hack though. See my response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64006395/9090751

Comment: I will check that entry point service. It might be helpful and cleaner than Dockerfile, as its image is just base for my bazel container image creator routine.

Comment: can you please add that second solution here as well? I ended up using it instead of this one, it is cleaner then updating image. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but mine was related to a file shared via a volume to a service I was not building with a Dockerfile, but pulling. I had shared a shell script that I used in docker-compose but when I executed it, did not have permission.

I resolved it by using chmod in the command of docker compose

```yaml
command: -c "chmod a+x ./app/wait-for-it.sh && ./app/wait-for-it.sh -t 150 -h ..."
volumes:
    - ./wait-for-it.sh:/app/wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: I later did something similar, where volume is same one used in other service. Only problem is which command to run, but I managed to use `chown` instead of `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to make it JustWork(TM), do the following (worked in 2024):

```yaml
version: '3.7'

x-configs:
  volumes:
    my-named-volume: &volume-my-named-volume 'my-named-volume:/whatever/path/i/need'
    my-other-named-volume: &volume-my-other-named-volume 'my-other-named-volume:/whatever/other/path/i/need'

services:
  myapp:
    image: myappimage
    # user: my-non-root-user
    volumes:
      - *volume-my-named-volume
      - *volume-my-other-named-volume

  fix-named-volumes-permissions:
    # the image doesn't matter; easiest to use the same as the target docker service
    image: myappimage
    user: root
    command: chmod 777 /whatever/path/i/need /whatever/other/path/i/need
    volumes:
      - *volume-my-named-volume
      - *volume-my-other-named-volume

volumes:
  my-named-volume:
  my-other-named-volume:
```

Every time you `docker compose up -d`, the permissions on the mounted named volumes will be corrected to 777 (still owned by root:root, though). Note that the "correction" needs to run merely once -- the 777 permissions are "persistent". In short: it JustWorks(TM) and it's a mystery why one has to use stackoverflow to get this done.