# How to mount a volume with docker-compose with owner www-data user of the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have my docker-compose like below

```
  "kj_wordpress":
    image: kristijorgji/wordpress-php-7.1:0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ${KJ_WORDPRESS_PATH}:/var/www/html/app
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: "kj_wordpress"
```

This is working fine and I can access one wordpress site.
The problem is that the user of nginx (www-data) cannot access write permissions on `wp-contents/uploads` and fails to upload images there.

I can fix that manually by entering inside the running container like

`docker-compose exec kj_wordpress /bin/bash`

then run

`chown -R www-data wp-content/uploads/`

That works great.

Now I want to automate the process and not have to run that every time the container is created and run.

How can I make `www-data` user ot
- ${KJ_WORDPRESS_PATH}:/var/www/html/app

so the container path `/var/www/html/app`

Comment: Docker doesn't manage the ownership of either host-directory or named-volume content.  If `$KJ_WORDPRESS_PATH` is a host directory, you might be able to `sudo chown` that host directory to the right (numeric) uid; I'd also expect your `docker-compose exec ... chown` command to "stick" in this case.

Comment: @DavidMaze that is what I am doing now as also mentioned in the post. I just wanted to automate this in some other way. Currently I added in my entrypoint script that part to manually chown as first thing

Answer (score 1):

I had similar if not same question 2 years ago. There were few options, I tested marked answer until some point.

[Docker-compose and named volume permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027052/docker-compose-and-named-volume-permission-denied)

This is how I did it with docker compose later.

```yaml
    files-init:
        image: alpine
        restart: "no"
        entrypoint: |
            /bin/sh -c "chown myuser:myuser /path/to/folder"
        volumes:
            - logs:/path/to/folder
    service-logs:
        image: alpine
        depends_on:
            - files-init
    volumes:
        logs:
```

Comment: i think im looking for something similar here.  i want to chown my workspace to the user before i switch that user in the docker file.  (basically anything that root installed, change to 'myuser' ownsership, then switch to 'myuser'.