# Docker containr has no write permission

Tags: docker, permissions, grafana, volume

I'm new to Docker and I'm playing with volumes, images, containers and so on.

One of my last attempt was to take some data inside a container and bring them to a volume so, if I would kill the container, I would be able to re-run with the same settings as before.

To copy the content from inside the container (it's a Grafana instance) to host I used

```
docker cp grafana:/var/lib/grafana /home/nicola/Documenti/
```

Then I created the new volume with the classic `docker volume create grafana-storage`

Then I attached the new volume to a temporary container

```
docker container create --name temp -v grafana-storage:/data bash
```

and then I copied the old data from my host to the volume

```
docker cp grafana temp:/data
```

and deleted the temporary container.

Now, if I run a new instance of grafana with the new volume like below

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana \
  --volume grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana \
  grafana/grafana-oss
```

The container exits with the following error

```
GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.

You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migrate-to-v51-or-later

mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied

GF_PATHS_DATA='/var/lib/grafana' is not writable.

You may have issues with file permissions, more information here: http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migrate-to-v51-or-later

mkdir: can't create directory '/var/lib/grafana/plugins': Permission denied
```

What type of permissions do I need to set to the folder I copy inside the volume?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File ownership after docker cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613326/file-ownership-after-docker-cp)

Comment: @Rob the issue is I don't know the user that Grafana uses inside its container. Also, the container exit and I can't login as superuser

Comment: You could inspect the Dockerfile used by the image. For example, [this one](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) indicates UID and GID are set to 472. Alternatively, can you just create a fresh container and inspect the GID and GID there after copying the files?

Comment: @Rob I'm trying the `tar` option but I'm unable to use it for the whole folder

Comment: In theory, tar should work for both single files and directories. What exact command are you using and is there any error message?

Comment: @ROb if I use `tar -cf - . --mode u=+r,g=-rwx,o=-rwx --owner root --group root | docker cp - temp:/data` to copy the current folder inside the volume I got an _successfully copied 0B to temp:/data_ so it has copied nothing

Comment: While using `tar -cf grafana.tar grafana` correctly creates the archive